# Poisson and subharmonic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\Omega)$ solution of

$\Delta u(x) = f(u(x))$ for all $x\in \Omega$

$u(x)=0$ for all $x\in \partial\Omega$

$\\$

I want to show now that:

a) if $0 \leq f(v)$ with $v\in \mathbb{R}$ then $u(x)<0$ for all $x\in \Omega$ or $u(x)=0$ for all $x\in \Omega$

$\\$

b) if $f$ monotonical increasing and $v\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\Omega)$

$\Delta v(x) = f(v(x))$ for all $x\in \Omega$

$0\leq v(x)$ for all $x\in \partial\Omega$

then it holds $u(x) \leq v(x)$ for all $x\in \Omega$

I have no clue how this should work out.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I \think you might want $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar \Omega)$ etc.  Am I right?  Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried applying the maximum principle for subharmonic functions? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function